# Python passing a file as arg in launch.json?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, interpreter

Just getting back into Python, so very rusty. Is there a way to pass a file that is in a local directory as an argument in vsCode? I'm implementing a scanner that will generate tokens of a .txt file, but have to add the file name in my test scanner. Works perfectly fine, however, I would like to pass that as an arg in a command line so that I can have multiple different files in the directory and just all upon them, just like

```
myTestScanner.py exampleFile.scl
```

I have implemented a `sys.argv[0]` and added the example file I want to scan as an arg to pass but it tries to read the current testScanner file instead. What needs to be done?

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "args": ["${exampleFile.txt}"],
        "console": "integratedTerminal"
    }
}]
```

And the Scanner block to call for example file

```
myScanner = Scanner(sys.argv[0])
results = open('results.txt', 'w')
```

Comment: That's because sys.argv[0] is the name of your script. sys.argv[1] would be the argument passed on the command line (if there was one)

Comment: @OlvinRoght You nailed it. A very simple miss that I did not catch. Thank you so very much.